# Affect on Netting on Fruit trees that have Flowers and Bees

Tags: pollination, protection

I am looking to use a Tree net for my fruit trees to protect them from Birds and Squirrels . One of the trees I plan to spread it over is the " Manilkara zapota " Tree. I had some good production this past month but most of them were lost being eaten up . But it still has a lot of unriped fruits and I was planning to apply the net over it.

Now , While I was standing under it yesterday, I saw it still has a lot of Flowers and literally over 10-15 Bees on those flowers , which are needed for pollination. Now if I was to use the Netting, then I am guessing that would also affect these bees from entering the tree to help in pollination .

One Option I was thinking of going with is the one with a larger mesh size to allow bees through, but small enough for squirrels and Birds. But before I went ahead, wanted to ask the community how important would those bees be for the fruits ? 
Can I proceed with netting without worrying about them  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your netting is wide-meshed enough, most likely the bees won't be bothered by it.

For a bee it makes no difference whether a string from the net, a twig or something else is in the way. It will just be some kind of obstacle to fly around.